# How should I obtain an appropriate boolean result?

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I've written some code and here's a short bit

```
x = ['apple, iphone','samsung, galaxy','oneplus, 10pro']
print('apple' in x)
```

how do I get this statement as true, since apple already exists in x, I still keep getting the False as the boolean value.

Comment: `'apple'` isn't in `x`, `'apple, iphone'` is.

Answer (score 4):

When the `in` operator is applied to a list like you have here it looks for an exact match in the list. Your code is returning false because `'apple'` isn't in the list, `'apple, iphone'` is. To check each element in the list for the substring `'apple'` you could use list comprehension. Something like:

```py
x = ['apple, iphone','samsung, galaxy','oneplus, 10pro']
print(True in ['apple' in s for s in x])
```

What the second line does is use list comprehension to build a list of booleans indicating if the substring `'apple'` is in that element. Then it checks if `True` is in the resulting list.

or instead of using the `in` operator:

```py
x = ['apple, iphone','samsung, galaxy','oneplus, 10pro']
print(any(['apple' in s for s in x]))
```

The `any` built-in function returns true if any element in an iterable is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['apple, iphone','samsung, galaxy','oneplus, 10pro']
print(True in ('apple' in d for d in x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a function like this:

```
IsItemInList(item, list):
     for x in list:
          if x == item:
                return True
      return False
```

Pretty sure theres a much cleaner way to do this but that was my first guess. As we know, the first is mostly the worst.